# PHPunit tests for socialite login with google

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-socialite

I am using `socialite` in my application so that users can login with their google accounts. I want to write a functional test for this. So far I have got up to clicking the button to login,

```
public function testAuth()
    {
        $this->visit('/admin')
            ->see('The Admin Dashboard')
            ->click('Login with Google')

            //tests to login should go here

            ->seePageIs('/admin/dashboard');
    }
```

from here a method calls the `socialite google driver`, checks if the google email is corporate, and creates an account for the user in the database who can then access the dashboard. The problem is even if I mock a user, the moment the tests hit this `->click('Login with Google')` it sends a request to google and returns a `request failed error`

Comment: Not sure if you could write this test entirely functional. Perhaps you should try Codeception with Laravel5 module or Selenium if you have JS.

Comment: I don't want to use Codeception and I have no JS.... I will try to mock a logged in user without following the login process(not a good idea). But I will still be on the lookout for an answer